# Not sure if my code is working in Android 4.4?

Tags: visualforce, html, android

I think my code is not working in Android 4.4 either using browser or apps.

Initially I use

```
<apex:inputFile value="{!att.body}" filename="{!att.name}"/>
```

But I could not click to choose file.So I change to

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="attachmentFile"/>
```

Still I could not click to choose the file.However it works fine in Android 4.2,4.3 and 5.0.

Any solution on this?